# Is there anything analoguos to Task Manager?(kill specific programs)

Tags: freeze

So when my ubuntu freezes, is there a way I could kill only *some* programs not all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what exactly you mean by "freeze", but generally, if X (the "graphical mode") does not react anymore, a good way to kill some programs (or the program that's causing the freeze) is to do the following:

1. Use the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get into the non-graphical pure command-line mode.
2. Log in.
3. Use the command `killall programname` to kill the program you want to kill. For instance, type `killall firefox`. If you are unsure what the program name is, you can use the command `ps aux` to examine the list of currently running programs. You can also restart the X server altogether by using the command `sudo service lightdm restart`.
4. (Optionally) log out again by typing `exit` or using the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.
5. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to get back into X.

Comment: indeed this seems to be closely analogous to task manager

Comment: When my Ubuntu freezes due to low memory, it doesn't respond to Ctrl + Alt + F1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `htop`. One of the features is killing processes using F9.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is creating a keyboard shortcut. 
Search for keyboard in the launcher, go to shortcuts
Create a new custom shortcut give it a name like "System Monitor"
Add the command "gnome-system-monitor"
Bind this to a shortcut like control-alt-delete

When pressing the keys you will see all processes and other resources

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use pkill from the Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can kill the processes with `htop` from TTY1.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
2. Login with your username and password.
3. You may need to install `htop` first:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install htop
   ```
4. Run

   ```
   htop
   ```
5. Press <kbd>F6</kbd>, then use the <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> keys to highlight `CPU%` or `MEM%`, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It is now sorted by CPU or memory.
6. Highlight the process you want to kill with <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd>.
7. Press <kbd>F9</kbd>, select the kill signal then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to send it.
8. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to return to the desktop GUI.

Note: In step 5, you can also press <kbd>F3</kbd> and type part of the process name to search for it.